# Get cell to show as string in excel

Tags: excel, xlrd

I have a cell which shows the following:

```
00002
```

This is a string identifier and not a number.

However, when I click on the cell, it treats it as a number. It says "2" in the text input at the top (next to the formula).

How would I convert this to be a string? If I do cell formatting as Text, it strips all the leading zeros and incorrectly turns it into "2". Right now it is formatted as a zip code.

How do I make it a string, such that I can grab the value "00002" using xlrd?

Comment: Setting the cells format as text **before** you have entered the value in will do what you want.  The leading 0's are stripped once the **number** format is selected.  You would have to add them back in after you changed it to **text**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is the cell set to a custom format of 00000 ?
If so, you can convert it by using a formula:

```
=TEXT(A1,"00000")
```

Then copy -> paste-special -> values

Answer (score 0):

Under Format Cells option in the Number tab.  Change the category to 'Text'.

Comment: I mentioned that I already tried that in the question. It turns the cell into "2".

Comment: Interesting I have it set to Text and it shows the leading 0's for me.  Apologies